# SQL joining & limiting

Tags: mysql

At the moment, I'm writing a model system for my framework Scaffold. However, my SQL skills aren't that great. My system, at the moment, is producing this query.

```
SELECT 
 `User`.`id` AS `User_id`,
 `User`.`name` AS `User_name`,
 `Address`.`id` AS `Address_id`,
 `Address`.`address` AS `Address_address`,
 `Address`.`user_id` AS `Address_user_id`,
 `Database`.`id` AS `Database_id`,
 `Database`.`user_id` AS `Database_user_id`
FROM
 `users` AS `User`,
 `addresses` AS `Address`,
 `databases` AS `Database`
GROUP BY `User_id`,`Address_id`,`Database_id`
HAVING
 `User`.`id` = 1 AND
 `Address`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` AND
 `Database`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`;
```

Which produces this result.

```
User_id    User_name    Address_id    Address_address    Address_user_id    Database_id    Database_user_id
=======    =========    ==========    ===============    ===============    ===========    ================
1          Nat          1             1234               1                  1              1
1          Nat          1             1234               1                  2              1
1          Nat          2             3456               1                  1              1
1          Nat          2             3456               1                  2              1
```

That works fine, but I know I'm probably not doing it the best way (I should probably be making use of real joins?) and it makes what I can do from here extremely limited.

For example, if I wanted to limit to one address (for a oneToOne relationship) while not affecting the oneToMany databases relationship. How would I modify this SQL to do that?

Is this the best idea to even do with one query?

Comment: From my understanding of what your structure is, a `User` may have many `Address`, but you only want to show a maximum of 1?

Comment: Yes, but still show all the Database rows.

Answer (score 1):

No need to GROUP your current query:

```
SELECT 
    `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, 
    `Address`.`id` AS `Address_id`, `Address`.`address` AS `Address_address`, `Address`.`user_id` AS `Address_user_id`, 
    `Database`.`id` AS `Database_id`, `Database`.`user_id` AS `Database_user_id` 
FROM `users` AS `User`,
    JOIN `addresses` AS `Address` ON `Address`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
    JOIN `databases` AS `Database` ON `Database`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
WHERE `User`.`id` = 1;
```

To get just one User record, you need to find a way to either logically limit your Address & Database records that you're retrieving (using MAX or other Aggregate functions) based on your application's requirements, or else just group concat them for later parsing by your application, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`Address`.`id`, ',', `Address`.`address`, ',', `Address`.`user_id`) SEPARATOR '|') AS `Addresses`
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`Database`.`id`, ',', `Database`.`user_id`) SEPARATOR '|') AS `Databases`
FROM `users` AS `User`,
    JOIN `addresses` AS `Address` ON `Address`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
    JOIN `databases` AS `Database` ON `Database`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
WHERE `User`.`id` = 1
GROUP BY `User`.`id`;
```

Note limitations of the GROUP_CONCAT (1024 characters by default, but configurable)... using it here just for example.

**EDIT**:  Another point you should take from the examples above is never to use a HAVING clause where you can use a WHERE clause to do the same.  WHERE is significantly faster. Only use a HAVING clause to test the results of aggregate operations.

Comment: why `HAVING` and not `WHERE`?

Comment: That was leftover from the OP.  Changed it seconds after my initial post.